# how to reset text box values with out page reload

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

I need to reset my values in text box with out reloading the page.
Below is the which i use currently for reset but on click of reset page is reloaded.
Can any one please advise the code to reset without page reload.Is it possible only through Javascript

```
protected void BtnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    txt1.Text = string.Empty;
    txt2.Text = string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: You need to use JavaScript on the client to do this. C# only runs on the server portion.

Comment: Take a look here: [HTMLFormElement.reset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.reset)

Answer (score 1):

you can use html

```
<input type="reset" value="reset"/>
```

this will clear the form fields value

Comment: Isn't that exactly what I said? :=). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21465127/how-to-reset-text-box-values-with-out-page-reload?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Answer (score 1):

One option is to wrap all of your controls in an UpdatePanel.  You'll still have a postback, but it will be done via AJAX and won't refresh the [entire] page (so you wont get the flicker).  That will let you use the function you wrote.

If you don't need the postback and there is nothing that you need/want to handle serverside, then use the HTML reset button as Pradeep suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in Javascript it's just:

```
document.getElementById("txt1").value = "";
document.getElementById("txt2").value = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reset your whole form, just replace your asp.net button, with an HTML one.

So replace something like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="BtnReset" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

with:

```
<input id="Reset1" type="reset" value="reset" />
```

(type="reset" : will reset your form to original values)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the jQuery that will let you rest the specific textboxes.

You can also use regular input button since it doesn't require post back.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt1" />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt2" />
<asp:Button ID="btn1"
    runat="server"
    OnClientClick="return resetButtonClick();"
    Text="Reset" />
<input type="submit" value="Reset" 
    onclick="return resetButtonClick();" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function resetButtonClick() {
        $("#<%= txt1.ClientID %>").val("");
        $("#<%= txt2.ClientID %>").val("");
        return false;
    }
</script>
```